# Factor $x^8 + x^2 + 13$ into irreducible polynomials in $\Bbb F_{23} [x]$.

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials, cryptography, polynomial-rings

I want to factor  $x^8+ x^2 + 13$ into irreducible polynomials in $\Bbb F_{23} [x]$. I am trying using the method given in this link but not able to find its factors. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

[Factor $X^4 + 3$ into irreducible factors in $F_7[X]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3128373/factor-x4-3-into-irreducible-factors-in-f-7x)

Comment: A quick spreadsheet shows $x-10$ and $x-13$ are both factors.

Comment: That's not going to be so easy. I'd say this was a job for a CAS not by hand.

Comment: [Sagemath](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxz07NJtFOwVXB30zAy1uQK0rOpAHED8nMq8_JzMxNzgjLz0jXcNLnSgKIVcRYK2kDSCEgaGnOl6aUlJpfkF2loAgCSvhL_&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

Comment: Unless some special tricks work, this is usually best left to a CAS of your choice. The algorithms by [Cantor-Zassenhaus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Zassenhaus_algorithm) and/or [Berlekamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%27s_algorithm) have been implemented on, I believe, every CAS. For an annotated example use of Cantor-Zassenhaus see [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/893882/11619). That time it was more about finding the zeros (i.e. the linear factors).

Answer (score 4):

I'd start by viewing this as $y^4+y+13$, where $y=x^2$. Does that factor? Search for linear factors by testing numbers as roots. It takes a little patience (or a calculator) but $y=8$ is a root. So you have $$(y-8)\left(y^3+8y^2-5y+7\right)$$
Does this factor further? Only if the cubic has a root. Checking for roots, it does not. So you have:
$$(x^2-8)\left(x^6+8x^4-5x^2+7\right)$$
Does $x^2-8$ factor? Again checking for linear factors, we find a pair.
$$(x-10)(x-13)\left(x^6+8x^4-5x^2+7\right)$$

Could that sixth degree polynomial factor further?

- There are no linear factors. (If it had a root, then the cubic from before would have had a root.)
- It could factor into a quadratic and an irreducible quartic. But for the original polynomial $f$, $f(x)=f(-x)$. So the map $x\to -x$ must permute the factors (while negating any odd-degree factor). In this case, the trivial permutation. So that quadratic would have to have no linear term, and the quartic would have no linear term nor a cubic term. This would make our cubic in $y$ from earlier factorable, which we know it is not.
- It could factor into three quadratics. Again, the map $x\to-x$ might preserve all three quadratics, but that means none of them have linear terms and our cubic in $y$ would have been factorable. The other possibility is that it only preserves one quadratic, and we have $$\begin{align}x^6+8x^4-5x^2+7&=(x^2+a)(x^2+bx+c)(x^2-bx+c)\\&=x^6+(2c+a)x^4+(c^2+2ac)x^2+ac^2\end{align}$$ from which we deduce $a=8-2c$, so $$\begin{align}x^6+8x^4-5x^2+7&=x^6+8x^4+(c^2+2(8-2c)c)x^2+(8-2c)c^2\\&=x^6+8x^4+(16-3c^2)x^2+(8-2c)c^2\end{align}$$ Can $16-3c^2$ equal $-5$? Then $3c^2=21$, and $c^2=7$. But $7$ is not a square mod $23$, which can be checked by inspection.
- It could factor into two cubics. Again , $x\to -x$ permutes the factors (and since both are odd-degree, negates them at the same time).  It is impossible for the map $x\to-x$ to preserve the cubics while negating them, or each factor is of the form $x^3+ax$, and $0$ would be a root. It follows that they are negated and nontrivially permuted. So $$\begin{align}x^6+8x^4-5x^2+7&=(x^3+ax^2+bx+c)(x^3-ax^2+bx-c)\\&=x^6+(2b-a^2)x^4+(b^2-2ac)x^2-c^2\end{align}$$ Since $-7$ *is* a square, we can deduce wlog that $c=4$. So $$\begin{align}x^6+8x^4-5x^2+7&=x^6+(2b-a^2)x^4+(b^2-8a)x^2+7\end{align}$$ Now can we solve $2b-a^2\equiv8$ with $b^2-8a\equiv-5$? You can try each value of $a$ in the first relation to get a value of $b$, and try that in the second. You find $a\equiv1$, $b\equiv16$ works. So we have a factorization: $$\begin{align}x^6+8x^4-5x^2+7&=(x^3+x^2+16x+4)(x^3-x^2+16x-4)\end{align}$$

And then we conclude with: $$(x-10)(x-13)(x^3+x^2+16x+4)(x^3-x^2+16x-4)$$

Answer (score 2):

Using a CAS, we get $f(x) = (x - 10)(x + 10)(x^3 - x^2 - 7x - 4)(x^3 + x^2 - 7x + 4).$

Looks pretty painful to figure this out by hand, in particular the cubics.

Comment: Maybe we can check for roots, find $10$ is a root, conclude $-10$ is also a root, divide by $x^2-10^2$, and then write the result as $g(x)g(-x)$ with $g(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ and solve for $a,b,c$.

Comment: How did you get that after dividing its factor will be of form g(x)*g(-x)?

Comment: If $\pi(x)$ is an irreducible factor, then so is $\pi(-x)$. The issue I don't see past though is how to rule out irreducible factors for which $\pi(x)=\pi(-x)$.

Comment: @runway44 nice approach

Comment: @runway44 The factors with $\pi(x)=\pi(-x)$ are polynomials in $y=x^2$. They would show up in the process outlined in the early parts of Alex Jordan's answer.